# How to get one object at a time from the array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I created an array and to add the id of each order that I scan by Barcode Scanner.

**order.page.ts**

```
console.log('returned data: ', infoPedido.data);
```

**console**

Its returning in that way on my console:

```
returned data:  (2) ['000', '111']
                  0: "000"
                  1: "111"
                  length: 2
```

**payload**

I need to make it returns in my console, in that format

```
orders: [
    {"order":{
        "codpedido":integer}
    }
    {"order":{
        "codpedido":integer}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns a new item for every item in an array.

```
const mappedData = infoPedido.data.map(code => {
  return { order: { codpedido: code } }
})
console.log({ orders: mappedData })
```

Comment: Its exactly that! Thank you so much Alex!!